# Hosting Quart Application On Vercel. Quart Not Found When Deploying

Tags: python, flask, quart

So I am trying to deploy my dashboard for my Discord Bot on Vercel and when I do, the deploy fails. It says cannot find package Quart. I have included this and its version in the requirements.txt file. Here is the text file:

```
aiofiles==0.6.0
aiohttp==3.7.3
aiosqlite==0.17.0
astroid==2.4.2
Async-OAuthlib==0.0.9
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
asyncpraw==7.2.0
asyncprawcore==2.0.1
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==20.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
blinker==1.4
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
dblpy==0.4.0
discord-ext-ipc==2.0.0
discord.py==1.6.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
future==0.18.2
giphy-client==1.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
greenlet==1.0.0
h11==0.12.0
h2==4.0.0
hpack==4.0.0
Hypercorn==0.11.2
hyperframe==6.0.0
idna==2.10
iniconfig==1.1.1
isort==5.6.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
joblib==1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
livereload==2.6.3
lunr==0.5.8
Markdown==3.3.4
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mkdocs==1.1.2
multidict==4.7.6
nltk==3.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
packaging==20.7
pluggy==0.13.1
praw==7.2.0
prawcore==2.0.0
priority==1.3.0
py==1.9.0
pygame==2.0.1
PyJWT==2.0.1
pylint==2.6.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-utils==2.5.6
PyYAML==5.4.1
Quart==0.14.1
Quart-Discord==2.1.4
ratelimiter==1.2.0.post0
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.11
termcolor==1.1.0
toml==0.10.2
tornado==6.1
tqdm==4.59.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
update-checker==0.18.0
urllib3==1.26.2
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
wsproto==1.0.0
yarl==1.5.1
```

All other packages are installed besides Quart and Quart-Discord. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Vercel only supports Python 3.6 ([docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/python/python-version)), whereas Quart 0.14.1 requires at least Python 3.7. Quart 0.6.* are the final releases to support Python 3.6 if you want to switch to them, however there are features missing compared to 0.14.* see the [changelog for details](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst).